# an example where $ \phi (x) = \sup_{n \in Z^+} f_n(x)$ is not continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, equicontinuity

a)
Give an example where $$ \phi (x)  = \sup_{n \in Z^+} f_n(x)$$ is not continuous.

b) Prove that if one assumes that the sequence {$f_n$} is an equicontinuous family, then $\phi : [0,1] \rightarrow R$ defined in part a) is continuous.

My professor provided an example where $f_n(x) = -(\sin(\pi x))^n$ However, I do not see why this example is not continuous and I'm lost for part b).

Comment: For a), for $x=1/2$ $\phi(1/2) = -1$ while everywhere else $\phi =0$.

Comment: For b) this follows from Ascoli's theorem.

Comment: The Ascoli theorem says there exists a uniformly convergent subsequence, not continuity. Could you explain a little more?